# Drawing curved lines in AndEngine

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I am new to AndEngine and very happy that it's very easy and exciting thing to do. Unfortunately I am unable to draw a curved line in AndEngine.

Actually my scenario is that I have an animated sprite say Object. I want to move this object on a Line with the points given onToucing and dragging it. Now the problem is that I can't find any method to draw a line on points in a way that it does not produce corners. I want a smooth line with no corners.

Suppose I touch the object and drag it on the screen with the points of a square type region. But I don't want the corners in it. I want curves. Previously I am doing this by using quadTo(..) function of android to do this. All I want is a complete alternative to quadto function in AndEngine but with same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stitch together the curved line from many many small straight lines.

Moving an object along a line is a very different task though. You'd want to have a look at CubicBezierMoveModifier and QuadraticBezierMoveModifier for those.

Maybe you can actually use the code in those modifiers to create your 'smooth' line.

Comment: Didn't get ant thing from the internet. How to draw those curves.?

Comment: Well I would like to add this into your knowledge that I have done this in android canvas by using Path and using quadto function and I was successful. Now I am looking for the alternative for this in andEngine. Is this possible?? If so please tell me how? The method told above by you doesn'd draw any thing but it just moves. Moving objects on curved line will not be difficult for me I have donw this already All I want to do is to draw that curve using multiple points. Tell me how thsi is possible in andEngine. If not possible tell me how can I do it in andEngine using my old method of path.

Comment: FYI: There is a new Modifer called CardinalSplineMoveModifier and CatmullRomMoveModifier. They allow you to lay an smooth curve through an arbitrary amount of points. It also has methods to get interpolated points between those control points, so that you can plot a Curve through a couple of those lines.