# AndEngine level problems with curved path

Tags: android, andengine

I found a similar link on SO : [andengine curved path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181947/andengine-level-editor-curve-path)

But it isn't answered

Also one more question : [question with some similar question and some answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180570/drawing-curved-lines-in-andengine)

In the response to last question it is stated as following 2 things can help in achieving w

1. CatmullRomMoveModifier
2. CardinalSplineMoveModifier

I searched hard for this things but I didn't find any working demo sample for this. can anyone help me with any sample code or something that ca help me getting curved smooth path in andengine levels ?

This is a dead stop for me now in my project.

Comment: @nicolas-gramlich  - Please help us in this with some sample code. There are people talking about it in internet but no reference or sample to help us out.

Comment: Let us know what you have done so far. Provide code snippets.